# Youtube Iframe is not working with Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to embed a youtube video to my website. it works on Internet Explorer, Firefox, Google Chrome and Vivaldi, but when I test it on Edge it shows nothing, like the video is hidden.

When i resize the browser(make Edge smaller), the iframe shows up.

Refreshing the site or deleting the cache didn't work.

hope someone can help.

here is my code:

```
<div>
 <span>Video</span>
 <iframe width="426" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oDiPFuZLCP4"  gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I Uploaded the code that i'm testing on Codepen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYLRgN

Comment: It seems to be working for me. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zareyq Open in Edge

Comment: Have you tried removing the sizes? width="426" and height="240". Try also playing the video in edge without iframe, copy paste the link https://www.youtube.com/embed/oDiPFuZLCP4 in Edge.

Comment: Removing the sizes don't help but the video worked on codepen, but not on my site. I also use Jquery to close/open (Show/hide) the div maybe is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone every Get a Malware waring for Microsoft Edge being malware. I have AVG antivirus and I got a warning that MS Edge was malware do you guys think its just a mistake. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9LOb.png)

Comment: your answer has no thing to do with the question !

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32651528)